# Microsoft Project 2007, Work Column doesn't add up

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-project, microsoft-project-2007

I am creating a project file and I have a set of 4 tasks each with subtasks.  In the "Work" column, I put the amount of work, in hours, for each subtask, but when it sums up at the task level it is always greater than the sum of the subtasks

For instance, I have task with 5 subtasks, one is 2 hours and the other 4 are 1 hour each.  But when it adds it up it says 8 hours.  I dont understand what I am doing wrong here, I just want to keep track of the hours used on the project so we can compare it to the baseline at the end.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you pls create a new file w/ default settings, verify the behaviour and attach a screenshot?

Comment: It seems to change when I assign the resources.  I assigned myself to all tasks and it jumped from 5 hours to 13.

Comment: Does everything have only one resource, or is it doubling some up to account for "man hours"?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just added myself as the resource for all tasks and it changed the totals

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, it seems that adding myself to the Tasks also added the amount of cumulative hours for that task.  So I removed myself from the tasks and only added to the subtasks and everything adds up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is correct. The parent task should not have a resource assigned to it. Only the sub tasks should have a resource assigned.